Why is the value returning undefined?
I'm trying to a chrome extension to track tweets that I type out and store them into a variable that can be displayed in the html code.  However, each  time I do a tweet there is just an undefined value.
Here is the code:
script.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const tweetButtonSelector   = 'div[data-testid="tweetButtonInline"]';
  const tweetTextareaSelector = 'div[aria-label="Tweet text"]';

  function trackTweet() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const tweetTextarea = document.querySelector(tweetTextareaSelector);
      if (tweetTextarea) {
        const tweetInput = tweetTextarea.innerText;
        console.log('User is tweeting:', tweetInput);
        chrome.storage.local.set({
          tweetInput: tweetInput
        }, function() {
          console.log('Tweet content saved:', tweetInput);
        });
      }
    }, 500);
  }

  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
          if (node.querySelector && node.querySelector(tweetButtonSelector)) {
            const tweetButton = node.querySelector(tweetButtonSelector);
            tweetButton.addEventListener('click', trackTweet);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  });

  const tweetButton = document.querySelector(tweetButtonSelector);
  if (tweetButton) {
    tweetButton.addEventListener('click', trackTweet);
  }
});

popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['tweetInput'], function (result) {
    console.log('Retrieved tweet content:', result.tweetInput);
    const tweetContent = document.getElementById('tweetContent');
    tweetContent.textContent = result.tweetInput || 'No tweet tracked yet.';
  });
});

hello.html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Tweet Tracker</title> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <p>Tweet Tracker</p>
    <input type="text" id="InputText" placeholder="Input Text">
    <button id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
    <p id="output">a</p>
    <p id="tweetContent">No tweet tracked yet.</p> 
</body> 
</html>

manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Tweet Tracker",
  "description": ".",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "background",
    "scripting",
    "storage"
],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://x.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://x.com/*"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  }
}

I tried testing the code by putting in
chrome.storage.local.get('tweetInput', function(result) {
  console.log(result.tweetInput); 
});

and
chrome.storage.local.get(null, console.log)

in the console, but that also returned undefined.

so, console.log('Tweet content saved:', tweetInput); outputs a value?

Remove document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { in your content script. It already runs after that event.

From what I read, here you may be doing it wrong - browser.storage.<storageType>.get returns a Promise, doesn't take a callback like you are doing

Callbacks are supported.
